# Trying to draw a simple rectangle with JPanel, but nothing is showing up

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, awt, paintcomponent

I am currently reading the book "Head First Java". The book is amazing and I am really enjoying reading it. But I have come to an abrupt halt. 
The book was going through GUI programming with the swing library, which turned out to be easier than I thought it would be. After the GUI portion of the chapter the book introduced drawing graphics, with the awt library and graphics objects. And this is where I am stuck. The following is my code, which compiles just fine but does not seem to want to render the rectangle.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTest
{
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DrawTest test = new DrawTest();
        test.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(70, 70, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It is most likely very obvious, but I am not seeing. I would very much appreciate a thorough answer, I am new to Java so I would like to understand fully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you dont add this panel somewhere to the frame

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Now that makes sense. But how should I do it ? Should I make an instance of the DrawPanel class and then add to the pane, via getContentPane().add()?

Comment: @AslambekHudajev: In Swing, as a convenience, the `add` method and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means you can write `frame.add(child);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to instantiate a `DrawPanel` and add it to `frame` in `DrawTest`. First include a constructor for `DrawPanel`, then add these lines in the `go()` method:

```
DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had a feeling that the answer would be rather straight forward.